# Error in assigning policy to aws function for usergroups accessing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have pre-signup function adds user to user groups. I am adding policy via CLI to authorize function to update userpool Groups, however, I am getting the following error:

```
> Could not get policies for auth: userPoolGroups Policies cannot be
> added for auth TypeError: Cannot destructure property
> `serviceWalkthroughFilename` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
>     at Object.getPermissionPolicies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-auth/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/index.js:248:61)
>     at Object.keys.forEach.resourceName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-auth/lib/index.js:231:67)
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at getPermissionPolicies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-auth/lib/index.js:226:37)
>     at Object.exports.askExecRolePermissionsQuestions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/service-walkthroughs/execPermissionsWalkthrough.js:144:78)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/165
Here I found that in amplify that functionality is not implemented yet, and they are suggesting to add policy to authorize function to call auth.
In this case I am getting following:

```
? Select which capability you want to update: Lambda function (serverless function)
? Select the Lambda function you want to update funcPreSignup
? Do you want to update the Lambda function permissions to access other resources in this project? Yes
? Select the category auth
? Auth has 2 resources in this project. Select the one you would like your Lambda to access projauth
? Select the operations you want to permit for projauth create, read, update, delete

You can access the following resource attributes as environment variables from your Lambda function
        AUTH_PROJ_USERPOOLID
? Do you want to invoke this function on a recurring schedule? No
? Do you want to configure Lambda layers for this function? No
Error: Cannot add funcPreSignup due to a cyclic dependency
    at checkForCyclicDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/extensions/amplify-helpers/update-amplify-meta.js:188:15)
    at AmplifyToolkit.updateamplifyMetaAfterResourceUpdate [as _updateamplifyMetaAfterResourceUpdate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/extensions/amplify-helpers/update-amplify-meta.js:114:9)
    at updateFunctionResource (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/index.js:144:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
There was an error adding the function resource
```

Even I see it modifies CloudFormation stack, it continues to error Anauthorized exception